# HP Pavilion D7-1225ez battery not charging (tried a second battery too!)

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, hp-pavilion

My HP Pavilion D7-1225ez has not been charging its battery and making a lot of noise (as well as getting very hot). "HP Battery Status" returned as "INVALID: battery not inserted properly..." which of course is NOT actually the case as the battery is placed correctly. It would work plugged in to the power and show 0% as the battery level. I thought it might be because of the fact that the laptop is 7 years old and so the battery must be dead.

So I bought a new battery on Amazon and a can of compressed air to eliminate any dust related causes. I also bought a SSD (Kingston 120GB V300).

The new battery came with 52% charge and for th first time in ages I could use the laptop without the power cables. I replaced the hard drive with the new SSD and switched on with a Ubuntu image containing USB to install it. However, within less than 10 mins laptop shut down. I then connected the power adapted to charge it. I went ahead and installed Ubuntu to the new SSD. For some reason the system gets stuck after the log-in page / the screen is purple and I can see the cursor but nothing else. Can't see any interface or command prompt.

Anyway, I switched it off and let it charge for few hours. For some reason now, the laptop doesn't switch on without being connected to the power. I switched the hard drives to check the status on Windows (as I can't see anything on Linux) and it shows as 5% battery. When I run the same "HP Battery Status Check" it returns "Replace".

Notes:

- although the old one is, the new battery is not a genuine HP battery but it is the right one (or at least should be)
- not sure if this is relevant at all but I use a power plug converter as my laptop came with a Swiss style plug which doesn't fit the UK sockets / this has not been an issue though...
- again not sure if this is relevant but the clock settings have been playing up / the clock and date seems to be far behind. I first realised his when all the browsers would give a certificate error for all the websites. After updating the date and time this is no longer the case. But after a week of the changes the date and time seems to have almost not changed at all
- System Details: AMD Turion(tm) X2 Ultra Dual-Core Mobile ZM-82 2.20GHz, 4GB RAM

I'm not sure if I should contact Amazon to ask for a replacement battery or simply return it. I was planning on even ordering a RAM upgrade to the max 2X4GB)..

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 99% sure your laptop is broken.  Replace the laptop, not the battery.  Or at least take the laptop to a repair specialist and see what they say.  You should be able to do that for free.  They might even be able to fix it.  You won't get a better answer here than that.  Someone needs to look at the laptop *physically*.

Comment: Thank you for your response - I will try to find a repair specialist tomorrow